# Scaling down the width of a view after doing rotation by using CGAffineTransformScale

Tags: ios

I have drawn a view(black rectangle) straight to the x-axis then I am applying some rotation by using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.Please see image 1 after rotation.[image: image1]

After this I need to reduce the width from that rotated position.
For that I am using CGAffineTransformScale but image is not scaling down along the slope.Please see image 2.[image: image2]

If I change width from bound property then it works fine.
Any idea why CGAffineTransformScale behaves like that.

Below is my sample code.

```
         **__block CGAffineTransform rotationTransform;
           rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
           lineview.transform = rotationTransform;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
                CGAffineTransform finalTransform  = CGAffineTransformScale(lineview.transform, 0.4, 1);
                lineview.transform = finalTransform;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to move the frame and change the width :)

```
 VIEW.frame = CGRectMake(0,39, 320, 111);
```

This is the format

```
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
```

Comment: After Applying transform you can't use frame. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform. You can use bound which I am doing.